# Iterate through sql script using different values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is part of my script:

```
DECLARE @dataId int = 123               

-- Here I run more SQL scripts using @dataId

Select from table A where id = @dataId 

-- So on it goes in other tables and delete and update other tables
```

My question is there a way I can enter 100 values in `@dataId` and it will iterate through the script in an order? Is there a simpler way to do this in SQL Server 2008 rather then manually entering `@dataId` each time?

Comment: Yes, you can use cursors for this. But, is it really necessary to do it on a loop?, maybe there is another way to do it with `JOINS`.

Comment: @Lamak - there is a big script i want to go through i am not sure if joins will work.

Comment: @NoviceMe - SQL can handle a bigger workload than you think, most probably.  Post your entire problem, and we may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your comment, then I guess that `CURSORS` are the way to go. Something like this should do:

```
DECLARE @dataId int

DECLARE DataIds CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT DataId
FROM YourTableWithDataIdsHere

OPEN DataIds
FETCH NEXT FROM DataIds INTO @dataId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- Here I run more SQL scripts using @dataId

    Select from table A where id = @dataId 

    -- So on it goes in other tables and delete and update other tables

    FETCH NEXT FROM DataIds INTO @dataId
END

CLOSE DataIds
DEALLOCATE DataIds
```